# android Lollipop primary color doesn't change

Tags: android, colors, android-actionbar

According to this page http://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html#ColorPalette

I can change my my action bar colors by changing the primary colors.

```
<resources>
<!-- your theme inherits from the material theme -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material">
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">#ff9688</item>
        <!--   darker variant for the status bar and contextual app bars -->
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">#00796B</item>
        <!--   theme UI controls like checkboxes and text fields -->
        <item name="android:colorAccent">#8BC34A</item>
   </style>
</resources>
```

However inserting this into my styles.xml file does no effect on action bar.

Comment: check your manifest. Did you give style to your application/activity?

Comment: Thank you! that was the prolem

Comment: great!...accept below given answer from CommonsWare so that it can help others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure that your manifest is using that theme.

For example, [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ActionBar/MaterialColor) applies custom tints to the `Theme.Material` action bar. It has a theme similar to yours, though I pull my colors out into color resources:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material">
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

Then, in my manifest, I apply the theme via the `android:theme` attribute in the `<application>` element in the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.commonsware.android.abmatcolor"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"/>

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="21"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name="ActionBarDemoActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```